# Printing variables doesn't work as expected - Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I want to count the number of comparisons and swaps in quicksort algorithm. 
This is my code :

```
public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data , int low , int high , int comparisons ,int swaps ){

    ArrayList<Integer> sortedData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(low< high) {
        int pivotIndex = low; // Assume first element is the pivot
        int pivot = data.get(low);// The pivot value
        data.set(pivotIndex, data.get(high));// Swap pivot with last item

        data.set(high, pivot);
        int i = low - 1;
        int j = high;


        do {                
            do {i++;} while (data.get(i)< pivot);
            do {j--;} while (j>=0 && data.get(j)> pivot);
            comparisons ++ ;
            if (i < j) {
                int temp = data.get(i);
                data.set(i, data.get(j));
                swaps ++ ;
                data.set(j, temp);
                swaps ++ ;
            }  
        } while (i < j);

        data.set(high, data.get(i));  // Put the pivot back in the middle
        swaps ++ ;
        data.set(i, pivot);
        swaps ++ ;

        quickSort(data, low, i - 1 , comparisons , swaps);// Recursive sort left list
        quickSort(data, i + 1 ,high ,comparisons , swaps);// Recursive sort right list
    }

    System.out.println("Quick S swaps :   " + swaps);
    System.out.println("Quick S comparisons :   " + comparisons);

    sortedData = data;

    return sortedData ; 
}
```

Although I put the print statements after the loops and the recursive functions, The output is swaps and comparisons with each loop !! 
they also increase until a specific point then decrease to return back to their start point !!

```
Quick S swaps :   2
Quick S comparisons :   1
Quick S swaps :   4
Quick S comparisons :   2
Quick S swaps :   6
Quick S comparisons :   3
Quick S swaps :   8
Quick S comparisons :   4
Quick S swaps :   10
Quick S comparisons :   5
..
..
..
..
..
Quick S swaps :   2986
Quick S comparisons :   1493
Quick S swaps :   2988
Quick S comparisons :   1494
Quick S swaps :   2990
Quick S comparisons :   1495
Quick S swaps :   2992
Quick S comparisons :   1496
Quick S swaps :   2994
Quick S comparisons :   1497
Quick S swaps :   2998
Quick S comparisons :   1499
Quick S swaps :   2998
Quick S comparisons :   1499
Quick S swaps :   2998
Quick S comparisons :   1499
Quick S swaps :   2994
Quick S comparisons :   1497
Quick S swaps :   2992
Quick S comparisons :   1496
Quick S swaps :   2990
Quick S comparisons :   1495
Quick S swaps :   2988
Quick S comparisons :   1494
Quick S swaps :   2986
Quick S comparisons :   1493
..
..
..
..
..
Quick S swaps :   12
Quick S comparisons :   6
Quick S swaps :   10
Quick S comparisons :   5
Quick S swaps :   8
Quick S comparisons :   4
Quick S swaps :   6
Quick S comparisons :   3
Quick S swaps :   4
Quick S comparisons :   2
Quick S swaps :   2
Quick S comparisons :   1
```

**Why does this happen ?? and how can I fix it ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int comparisons` and `int swaps` and local variables placed on the call stack. Each call to `quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data , int low , int high , int comparisons ,int swaps)` has its own copy of these variables.

Each time you make a recursive call, you pass a higher value of these variables to the next call, but when the recursive call returns, you see the lower values of earlier copies of these variables.

If you want a single `comparisons` variables and a single `swaps` variable, you can make them static or instance variables of the class that contains the `quickSort` method (and remove them from the method signature).

As for the variables being printed multiple times, you have to move the `println` statements outside your recursive method, since that method is called multiple times, and each time you print these variables.

For example:

```
...

private int comparisons = 0;
private int swaps = 0;

public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data , int low , int high)
{
    ...
}

public printCounters()
{
    System.out.println("Quick S swaps :   " + swaps);
    System.out.println("Quick S comparisons :   " + comparisons);
}

....

someObj.quickSort(data, 0, data.size() - 1); // sort the list
someObj.printCounters(); // print the counters
```

As an alternative, as JB Nizet commented, you can pass some mutable counter.

For example, an `int` array:

```
someObj.quickSort(data, 0, data.size() - 1, new int[]{0}, new int[]{0});
```

and

```
public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data , int low , int high , int[] comparisons ,int[] swaps)
{
    // here you change each comparisons++ to comparisons[0]++ 
    // and each swaps++ to swaps[0]++
    // you also print comparisons[0] and swaps[0]
}
```

Comment: Or pass mutable counters and increment them.